# Test APK Dependency Conflicts

Tags: java, android, gradle

Em uma aplicação antiga que fui atualizar a versão das dependências do gradle, ao executar recebi a seguinte mensagem a respeito de um conflito entre a versão da dependência `com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305` para app e para test:

> Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:preMyAppDebugAndroidTestBuild'. >
>   Conflict with dependency 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305' in project
>   ':app'. Resolved versions for app (1.3.9) and test app (2.0.1) differ.
>   See https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html
>   for details. * Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack
>   trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run
>   with --scan to get full insights. * Get more help at
>   https://help.gradle.org BUILD FAILED in 0s

Alguém já passou por algo similar? Como devo proceder? Segue abaixo minha lista de dependências:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:23.3-android'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.7.5'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:android-core:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:android-integration:3.2.0'
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.5'
    annotationProcessor 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.5'
    provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.5'
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2'){
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-v13'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que está acontecendo é que duas ou mais dependências estão dependendo dessa biblioteca `com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305`, mas em versões diferentes. Com isso, está ocorrendo esse conflito.

#### Forçar uma única versão

A primeira solução é forçar que o gradle compile apenas o número da versão que você declara para todas as dependências, não importando qual número de versão as dependências em si tenham declarado. Isso pode ser feito direto no arquivo `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
}
```

Nesse exemplo, estamos forçando a versão 1.3.9.

#### Descobrir em quais dependências está o conflito

Outra solução é avaliar toda sua árvore de dependencias e identificar quais dependências estão dependendo essa mesma biblioteca `findbugs` e realizar `exclude`nas incompatíveis.

Para isso, podemos usar o comando para listar toda nossas árvores de dependências:

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

Ou mesmo podemos pesquisar por um dependência em específico como `compile`, `testCompile` ou `androidTestCompile`:

```
./gradlew :app:dependencyInsight --configuration compile --dependency <name>
./gradlew :app:dependencyInsight --configuration testCompile --dependency <name>
./gradlew :app:dependencyInsight --configuration androidTestCompile --dependency <name>
```

No caso:

```
./gradlew :app:dependencyInsight --configuration compile --dependency com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305
./gradlew :app:dependencyInsight --configuration testCompile --dependency com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305
./gradlew :app:dependencyInsight --configuration androidTestCompile --dependency com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305
```

Mediante a lista de dependências especificadas, o problema está na biblioteca `com.google.guava:guava:23.3-android`, sendo assim, concluimos com o seguinte exclude:

```
compile ('com.google.guava:guava:23.3-android') {
   exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'
}
```